# IntelliJ .js file not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea

I was trying to add a new .js file but forgot to add an extension. I removed it and created a new one but intelliJ won't recognize it as a JavaScript File.

What I've tried:

- Removing it and re-creating it
- Commit it to git
- Restarting IntelliJ
- Rebooting the computer

The file:

**myComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const MyCOmponent = () => {
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 8):

You accidentally added your file name and extension to the list of files interpreted as a text file. To fix it you need to remove the specific file.

Navigate to IntelliJ settings either from the file menu `File -> Settings` or clicking the wrench in the toolbar:

[image]

Inside Settings you need to find the recognized file types by navigating
`Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> Text` then selecting your file's name in the list. Remove it by clicking the `-` in the option list to the right of the file extensions list, like so:

[image]

IntelliJ should now recognize your file as a normal `.js` file.